# Adjunction formula for holomorphic submersion

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f : X^{n} \to Y^{m}$  be a holomorphic submersion between two complex manifolds. Then given any point $x \in X$ we can find an open set $x \in U$ and local holomorphic coordinates $(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ on $U$ and $(y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ on $f(U)$ such that in these coordiantes the map $f$ is given by $(z_1, \ldots, z_n) \to (y_1, \ldots, y_m)$. If $f$ is proper with connected fibers, then the canonical bundle of every fiber $X_{y} = f^{-1}(y)$ satisfis $K_{X_{y}} \cong K_{X}|_{X_{y}}$.

The proof goes like: if $f$ is proper with connected fibers, then the adjunction formula gives $K_{X_{y}} \cong K_{X}|_{X_{y}} \otimes \text{det}(N_{X_y|X})$. The normal bundle is trivial, because its dual is gloabally trivialized by $f^{\ast}(dy_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dy_{m})$. What does this laset sentence mean? $dy_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dy_{m}$ is not even a global section on $K_{Y}$ and I do not see how it is possible to trivialize the determinant normal line bundle.

Update: For your reference, the above is taken from this [note](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04823.pdf), page 48.

Anyone has any thoughts on this? Has been struggling with it for days.

Comment: I'm not sure how the author you are reading is expecting you to see this, but the basic intuition is that since any two fibers are disjoint, the normal bundle to a fiber inside the total space of the fibration is always trivial.

Comment: OK, now I'm reading this again and I think the idea is that taking a nowhere vanishing local $m$-form on $f(U) \ni y$, we can pull that back to get a nowhere vanishing $m$-form on $f^{-1}(f(U))$ that then restricts to some sort of nowhere-vanishing tensor on the fiber. But exactly which tensor you want, and how that relates to the conormal bundle of the fiber I'm not sure.

Comment: I have added the source of the proof.

Comment: That is also what I thought, but even with this reasoning I am not quite sure why a local nowhere vanishing form can be used to show that the conormal bundle has a nowhere vanishing global section.@TabesBridges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author is saying is that $f^*(dy_1\wedge\dots dy_m)$ is a never-vanishing section of the line bundle $\det(N^*_{X_y|X})$ restricted to the fiber $X_y$. Indeed, $f^*dy_i,i=1,\dots,m$ are sections of $T^*X$ over $X_y$ which are in the kernel of the pullback map $\iota^*$ where $\iota:X_y\to X$, so they define sections of $N^*_{X_y|X}$ over $X_y$, which are linearly independent everywhere on $X_y$ so their wedge product trivializes $\det(N^*_{X_y|X})$ over $X_y$.